# How to round up from the hundredth point in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to turn convert 36.901775282237 to 36.91 in php which function do I use in order to convert to this value. I've tried the round function but it's not giving me the right value no matter what flag I use.

Comment: Yes this is a test that I'm trying to accomplish and I haven't found an answer.

Comment: No worries, the down-voting of question just indicates mainly on research effort. Please see whether the answers below help you / your colleague.

Comment: _"I've tried what I know and it didn't work"_ Please show your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, 36.901775282237 doesn't round up to 36.91 but rather rounds down to 36.90. You'll need to combine ceil with some custom math to get the rounding you're asking for. If you're looking for mathematically correct rounding, `number_format` will accomplish that internally:

```
function ceilWithPercision($number, $decimalPoint) {
    $number = $number * pow(10, $decimalPoint);
    $number = ceil($number);
    $number = $number / pow(10, $decimalPoint);
    
    return (string) $number;
}

$number = 36.901775282237;

var_dump(ceilWithPercision($number, 2)); // "36.91"
var_dump(number_format($number, 2));     // "36.90"
```

Example here: https://3v4l.org/NMOpH

Comment: @HPiere thanks for your help it gives the right result. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The normal way is to use number_format

```
<?php

$newvalue=number_format(36.901775282237,2);

echo $newvalue;

?>
```

But if you wish to do what you want , then use a few lines of codes. (I think no need to further explain, just simple math)

```
<?php

$value=36.901775282237;

//$value=36.900775282237; for this case the result will be 36.90


///// do the trick
$value=intval($value * 1000)/1000;
$parsex=number_format($value * 100,2, ".", "");
$parsex=ceil($parsex)/100;
//// end

echo $parsex; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at some of the [Php Documentation](https://www.php.net/docs.php), and maybe some tutorials online before asking these kinds of questions here.

What I think you are looking for is [number_format(36.901775282237, 2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: That's the reason I asked the question but I couldn't find what I was looking for in the docs. And no number_format is not what I'm looking for. It doesn't give the right result.